# package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist and more

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a web application project using Spring and IntelliJ, and it's been working great so far, but today I tried to run it and it starting giving me this errors

This is just a small part

```
Error:(27, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestParam
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(8, 47) java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
Error:(19, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestMapping
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(25, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestMapping
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(42, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestParam
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(28, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestParam
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(6, 38) java: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
Error:(9, 47) java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
Error:(44, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(43, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestParam
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(11, 26) java: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
Error:(41, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestMapping
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(29, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestParam
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
Error:(16, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Controller
Error:(7, 47) java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
Error:(26, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestParam
  location: class com.eina.as.controladores.ControladorHome
```

There's more errors but they're basically the same as above. I don't know what happened, I've tried to reimport the "pom.xml" but it does nothing. I've deleted and cloned the project a few times already.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does a "mvn clean compile" on command-line work? Did you import the project as a maven one?

Answer (score 0):

Clean the maven project. Then update the project snapshot or update maven project. Also check for the dependencies in m2 directory. Then again rebuild the project.

1. Clean Maven project. Project -> RightClick -> Run As -> Maven Clean
2. Update Maven Project.
   Project -> Right Click -> Maven -> Upadte Project
   A new window will open. Select the project and check mark the "Force Update of snapshot". and then update.
3. Rebuild the project. Right click-> Run as -> Maven install

Comment: How do I do that, step by step?